# Tracking a mousemove on overflowing content

Tags: javascript, css, overflow, overlay

Consider the following example where overlay is placed on top of an overflowing content:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

  overlay.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    alert("Fire callback with:", [e.clientX, e.clientY]);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

I'd like to have two things:

1. When mouse moves on top of the overlay, I'd like to know about it by firing a callback with mouse coordinates.
2. The overflowing content should be scrollable.

However, as you can see, only #2 is true due to `pointer-events: none`.

If `pointer-events: none` is removed, only #1 becomes true.

How could I achieve both #1 and #2?

Comment: How about listening the mousemove on `.inner-container`?

Comment: @Teemu Unfortunately, in my real use-case, this wouldn't work since the inner container is fully occupied by an iframe. So, the mouse move will be fired only when the mouse enters or leaves the inner container, but not when the mouse is moved inside the iframe.

Comment: So the overlay is actually on the top of an iframe, and the iframe is the scrolling element? These are fundamental details when answering the question, I think you should provide a more accurate example then ..?

Comment: @Teemu You are right. Here is a better example: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-newton-9ihk8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mousemove on .inner-container looks the simple solution. But if you really want to use the overlay this is also a solution.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    const bounding = overlay.getBoundingClientRect();
    const inVertical = e.clientY >= bounding.top && e.clientY <= (bounding.height + bounding.top);
    const inHorizontal = e.clientX >= bounding.left && e.clientX <= (bounding.width + bounding.left);
    if(inVertical && inHorizontal) {
      console.log("Fire callback with:", [e.clientX, e.clientY]);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```